# Cannot compile GLSL 3.30 shader with group array in Qt 4.7 application using QGLShaderProgram

Tags: qt, opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-3

I'm developing an application that uses Qt 4.7 with the goal of creating a simple 3D OpenGL viewer. I want to use GLSL 3.30 shaders. I use Linux Ubutu 11.10, my CG is a NVIDIA with a NVS 3100M GPU, the NVIDIA driver version is 280.13 and OpenGL version is 3.3.0

I have a working basic shader which doesn't compute any lighting. That is wanted to do next but I'm stuck with a problem.

Here is my not-working modified vertex shader.

```
#version 330

in vec3 inPosition;
in vec4 inColor;
in vec3 inNormal;
uniform mat4 inModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 inViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 inProjectionMatrix;
out vec4 exColor;

uniform Light {
    vec4 position;
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
} lights[4];

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = inProjectionMatrix * inViewMatrix * inModelMatrix * vec4(inPosition, 1.0);
    exColor = lights[0].ambient;
}
```

The OpenGL Shading Language reference for GLSL 3.30 states that:

```
uniform Transform { // API uses “Transform[2]” to refer to instance 2
    mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
    mat4 ModelViewProjectionMatrix;
    float Deformation;
} transforms[4];
...
... = transforms[2].ModelViewMatrix; // shader access of instance 2
// API uses “Transform.ModelViewMatrix” to query an offset or other query
```

So if I'm not mistaken, the code is correct. However, it doesn't even compile. The following error is thrown:

```
QGLShader::link: "Vertex info
-----------
Internal error: assembly compile error for vertex shader at offset 1805:
-- error message --
line 38, column 15:  error: expected '='
line 82, column 36:  error: expected ';'
-- internal assembly text --
!!NVvp4.1
OPTION NV_parameter_buffer_object2;
# cgc version 3.1.0001, build date Jul 27 2011
# command line args: 
#vendor NVIDIA Corporation
#version 3.1.0.1
#profile gp4_1vp
#program main
#semantic Light.lights
#semantic inModelMatrix
#semantic inViewMatrix
#semantic inProjectionMatrix
#var float4 gl_Position : $vout.POSITION : HPOS : -1 : 1
#var float4 lights[0].position : BUFFER[0] : buffer[0][0] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[0].ambient : BUFFER[0] : buffer[0][16] : -1 : 1
#var float4 lights[0].diffuse : BUFFER[0] : buffer[0][32] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[0].specular : BUFFER[0] : buffer[0][48] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[1].position : BUFFER[1] : buffer[1][0] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[1].ambient : BUFFER[1] : buffer[1][16] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[1].diffuse : BUFFER[1] : buffer[1][32] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[1].specular : BUFFER[1] : buffer[1][48] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[2].position : BUFFER[2] : buffer[2][0] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[2].ambient : BUFFER[2] : buffer[2][16] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[2].diffuse : BUFFER[2] : buffer[2][32] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[2].specular : BUFFER[2] : buffer[2][48] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[3].position : BUFFER[3] : buffer[3][0] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[3].ambient : BUFFER[3] : buffer[3][16] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[3].diffuse : BUFFER[3] : buffer[3][32] : -1 : 0
#var float4 lights[3].specular : BUFFER[3] : buffer[3][48] : -1 : 0
#var float3 inPosition : $vin.ATTR0 : ATTR0 : -1 : 1
#var float4 inColor :  :  : -1 : 0
#var float3 inNormal :  :  : -1 : 0
#var float4x4 inModelMatrix :  : c[0], 4 : -1 : 1
#var float4x4 inViewMatrix :  : c[4], 4 : -1 : 1
#var float4x4 inProjectionMatrix :  : c[8], 4 : -1 : 1
#var float4 exColor : $vout.ATTR0 : ATTR0 : -1 : 1
PARAM c[12] = { program.local[0..11] };
CBUFFER buf0[][] = { program.buffer[0..3] };
ATTRIB vertex_attrib[] = { vertex.attrib[0..0] };
OUTPUT result_attrib[] = { result.attrib[0..0] };
TEMP R0, R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8;
MOV.F R3, c[9];
MOV.F R2, c[8];
MUL.F R0, R3, c[5].y;
MOV.F R1, c[10];
MAD.F R0, R2, c[5].x, R0;
MAD.F R5, R1, c[5].z, R0;
MOV.F R0, c[11];
MAD.F R6, R0, c[5].w, R5;
MUL.F R4, R3, c[4].y;
MAD.F R5, R2, c[4].x, R4;
MAD.F R5, R1, c[4].z, R5;
MAD.F R5, R0, c[4].w, R5;
MUL.F R4, R6, c[1].y;
MAD.F R8, R5, c[1].x, R4;
MUL.F R4, R3, c[6].y;
M    UL.F R7, R6, c[0].y;
MAD.F R4, R2, c[6].x, R4;
MUL.F R3, R3, c[7].y;
MAD.F R2, R2, c[7].x, R3;
MAD.F R3, R1, c[6].z, R4;
MAD.F R1, R1, c[7].z, R2;
MAD.F R2, R0, c[6].w, R3;
MUL.F R4, R6, c[2].y;
MAD.F R0, R0, c[7].w, R1;
MAD.F R3, R2, c[1].z, R8;
MAD.F R1, R0, c[1].w, R3;
MAD.F R7, R5, c[0].x, R7;
MAD.F R3, R2, c[0].z, R7;
MAD.F R3, R0, c[0].w, R3;
MUL.F R1, vertex.attrib[0].y, R1;
MAD.F R1, vertex.attrib[0].x, R3, R1;
MUL.F R3, R6, c[3].y;
MAD.F R3, R5, c[3].x, R3;
MAD.F R3, R2, c[3].z, R3;
MAD.F R4, R5, c[2].x, R4;
MAD.F R3, R0, c[3].w, R3;
MAD.F R2, R2, c[2].z, R4;
MAD.F R0, R0, c[2].w, R2;
MAD.F R0, vertex.attrib[0].z, R0, R1;
ADD.F result.position, R0, R3;
LDC.F32X4 result.attrib[0], buf0[0][16];
END
# 41 instructions, 9 R-regs
"
```

If I remove the call to lights[0].ambient, the shader compiles but when I try to get the uniform location, it doesn't work:

```
int lightsLocation = shaderProgram.uniformLocation("Light[0]");

PFNGLGETUNIFORMLOCATIONPROC glGetUniformLocation = (PFNGLGETUNIFORMLOCATIONPROC)(context()->getProcAddress("glGetUniformLocation"));

qDebug() << lightsLocation << glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.programId(), "Light[0]"); // -1 -1
```

I've also tried this with "Light", "lights", "lights[0]", "lights[0].ambient" as uniform name with no success.

After some search, I've found this post: [Setting the values of a struct array from JS to GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202173/setting-the-values-of-a-struct-array-from-js-to-glsl) and thus tried to use structures as it is shown but this doesn't work either.

**Subsequent question**

Event if I could bring that to work thanks to some answer, I don't know which method of QGLShaderProgram I should use to upload the data.

**tl;dr**

1) Why doesn't the following code compile?
    out vec4 exColor;

```
uniform Light {
     vec4 ambient;
} lights[4];

void main(void) {
    exColor = lights[0].ambient;
}
```

2) What uniform name should one use as parameter of QGLShaderProgam::uniformLocation() to get the location of a `uniform Light { ... } lights[4];` or `struct Light { ... }; uniform Light lights[4];`?

3) Once the location is retrieved, what function of QGLShaderProgram should one use to upload the data to the GPU?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the error message for the mini shader example you give at the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You are missing "struct" before Light in order to be a structure.

or ...

Your code is legal, but it creates a *Uniform Block*, which is meant for easy sharing of large blocks of data between different shaders, and is not stored in shader uniform block but instead in a buffer object. If you intended to do that, then you need to include the following line at the beginning of the shader:

```
#extension GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object : enable
```

Note that this doesn't work with older NVIDIA GPUs (driver bug? it didn't work with older ATis either), but the same code works for me on GeForce GTX 560.

Also, get familiar with [GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/uniform_buffer_object.txt) (there is an example shader and code to set it up).

2) In case you are not using (referencing) a uniform, the compiler will optimize it away, that is why you can't get the uniform location. That may lead to frustration because one can't get uniform location even if using the correct name.

For uniform buffer, the layout of the data in memory is given by the specs, you then create a buffer object (glGenBuffers()), fill it with raw data (glBufferData()) and bind it to the uniform block using glGetUniformBlockIndex() and glUniformBlockBinding().

In case it was meant to be a "struct", you can always find names of active uniforms through glGetActiveUniformName() sou you can see what names to use. For your structure, you would need to use "lights[0].ambient" through "lights[3].ambient" to get uniform locations, and then call glUniform4f() four times to specify the data (because the variables pointed to are vectors).

3) already said that above. either glBufferData() for uniform block, or appropriate glUniform*() for uniforms. if in structure, you need to upload structure members separately. if in array of structures, still you need to upload structure members separately, for each structure in the array. if an array is a member of structure, only then you would use glUniform*v() to upload an array of floats/vectors/matrices.

Comment: I accept this as the correct answer as it is wath I, painfully, found out. I will however provide another answer with more details regarding the Qt part. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To handle the Uniform Buffer Objects in a similar way as Qt does for the Vertex Buffer Objects and Index Buffer Objects, I created this class:

```
#ifndef UNIFORMBUFFEROBJECT_H
#define UNIFORMBUFFEROBJECT_H

#include <qgl.h>

struct UBOInfoStruct {
    QString uniformName;
    GLuint progId;
    GLuint blockIdx;
    GLint blockSize;
    GLuint bindingIdx;
};

typedef UBOInfoStruct UBOInfo;

class UniformBufferObject
{
public:
    UniformBufferObject();

    bool create();
    bool isCreated() const;

    void destroy();

    bool bind();
    bool bind(GLuint progId, QString uniformName);
    void release();

    GLuint bufferId() const;

//    bool read(int offset, void *data, int count);
    void write(int offset, const void *data, int count);

    void allocate(const void *data, int count);
    inline void allocate(int count) { allocate(0, count); }


protected:
    static GLuint bindingIndex();
    static QVector<GLuint> m_bindingIndices;

    bool initFunctionPointers(const QGLContext* m_glContext);

    GLuint m_bufferId;

    const QGLContext* m_glContext;

    bool m_inited;

    QVector<UBOInfo> m_UBOInfos;

    PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC glBindBuffer;
    PFNGLBINDBUFFERBASEPROC glBindBufferBase;
    PFNGLBINDBUFFERRANGEPROC glBindBufferRange;
    PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC glBufferData;
    PFNGLBUFFERSUBDATAPROC glBufferSubData;
    PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSPROC glDeleteBuffers;
    PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC glGenBuffers;
    PFNGLGETACTIVEUNIFORMBLOCKIVPROC glGetActiveUniformBlockiv;
    PFNGLGETACTIVEUNIFORMSIVPROC glGetActiveUniformsiv;
    PFNGLGETUNIFORMBLOCKINDEXPROC glGetUniformBlockIndex;
    PFNGLGETUNIFORMINDICESPROC glGetUniformIndices;
    PFNGLUNIFORMBLOCKBINDINGPROC glUniformBlockBinding;
};

#endif // UNIFORMBUFFEROBJECT_H
```

CPP:

```
#include "uniformbufferobject.h"

#include <QGLContext>

#include <QDebug>

QVector<GLuint> UniformBufferObject::m_bindingIndices = QVector<GLuint>();

GLuint UniformBufferObject::bindingIndex() {
    for(GLuint i = 0, size = m_bindingIndices.size(); i < size; i++) {
        if(m_bindingIndices.at(i) != i) {
            m_bindingIndices.insert(i, i);
            return i;
        }
    }
    m_bindingIndices.append(m_bindingIndices.size());
    return m_bindingIndices.size();
}

UniformBufferObject::UniformBufferObject() :
    m_bufferId(0), m_glContext(NULL), m_inited(false),
    glBindBuffer(NULL), glBindBufferBase(NULL), glBindBufferRange(NULL), glBufferData(NULL), glDeleteBuffers(NULL), glGenBuffers(NULL),
    glGetActiveUniformBlockiv(NULL), glGetActiveUniformsiv(NULL), glGetUniformBlockIndex(NULL), glGetUniformIndices(NULL),
    glUniformBlockBinding(NULL)
{
}

bool UniformBufferObject::create() {
    const QGLContext* m_glContext = QGLContext::currentContext();

    if(m_glContext) {
        if(!m_inited && !initFunctionPointers(m_glContext)) {
            qDebug("Cannot find Uniform Buffer Objects related functions");
            return false;
        }

        GLuint tmpBufferId = 0;
        glGenBuffers(1, &tmpBufferId);

        if(tmpBufferId) {
                m_bufferId = tmpBufferId;
            this->m_glContext = m_glContext;

            return true;
        } else {
            qDebug("Invalid buffer Id");
        }
    }

    qDebug("Could not retrieve buffer");

    return false;
}

bool UniformBufferObject::isCreated() const {
    return (bool)(m_bufferId != 0);
}

void UniformBufferObject::destroy() {
    if(m_bufferId != 0) {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_bufferId);
    }
    m_bufferId = 0;
    m_glContext = NULL;
}

bool UniformBufferObject::bind() {
    if(!isCreated()) {
        qDebug("Buffer not created");
        return false;
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, m_bufferId);

    return true;
}

bool UniformBufferObject::bind(GLuint progId, QString uniformName) {
    GLuint tmpBlockIdx = glGetUniformBlockIndex(progId, uniformName.toUtf8());

    if(tmpBlockIdx == GL_INVALID_INDEX) {
        qDebug() << QString("Could not find block index of block named: %1").arg(uniformName);

        return false;
    }

    GLint tmpBlockSize;
    glGetActiveUniformBlockiv(progId, tmpBlockIdx, GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE, &tmpBlockSize);

    GLuint tmpBindingIdx = bindingIndex();
    glUniformBlockBinding(progId, tmpBlockIdx, tmpBindingIdx);

    glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, tmpBindingIdx, m_bufferId);

    if(glGetError() == GL_INVALID_VALUE || glGetError() == GL_INVALID_ENUM) {
        qDebug() << "ERROR";
    }

    UBOInfo info;
    info.progId = progId;
    info.uniformName = uniformName;
    info.blockIdx = tmpBlockIdx;
    info.blockSize = tmpBlockSize;
    info.bindingIdx = tmpBindingIdx;

    m_UBOInfos.append(info);

    return true;
}

void UniformBufferObject::release() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
}

GLuint UniformBufferObject::bufferId() const {
    return m_bufferId;
}

void UniformBufferObject::write(int offset, const void *data, int count) {
    if(!isCreated())
        return;

    bind();

    glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, offset, count, data);
}

void UniformBufferObject::allocate(const void *data, int count) {
    if(!isCreated())
        return;

    bind();

    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, count, data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}

bool UniformBufferObject::initFunctionPointers(const QGLContext* m_glContext) {
    glBindBuffer = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glBindBuffer");
    glBindBufferBase = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERBASEPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glBindBufferBase");
    glBindBufferRange = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERRANGEPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glBindBufferRange");
    glBufferData = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glBufferData");
    glBufferSubData = (PFNGLBUFFERSUBDATAPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glBufferSubData");
    glDeleteBuffers = (PFNGLDELETEBUFFERSPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glDeleteBuffers");
    glGenBuffers = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
    glGetActiveUniformBlockiv = (PFNGLGETACTIVEUNIFORMBLOCKIVPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glGetActiveUniformBlockiv");
    glGetActiveUniformsiv = (PFNGLGETACTIVEUNIFORMSIVPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glGetActiveUniformsiv");
    glGetUniformBlockIndex = (PFNGLGETUNIFORMBLOCKINDEXPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glGetUniformBlockIndex");
    glGetUniformIndices = (PFNGLGETUNIFORMINDICESPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glGetUniformIndices");
    glUniformBlockBinding = (PFNGLUNIFORMBLOCKBINDINGPROC)m_glContext->getProcAddress("glUniformBlockBinding");

    if(!glBindBuffer ||
            !glBindBufferBase ||
            !glBindBufferRange ||
            !glBufferData ||
            !glBufferSubData ||
            !glDeleteBuffers ||
            !glGenBuffers ||
            !glGetActiveUniformBlockiv ||
            !glGetActiveUniformsiv ||
            !glGetUniformBlockIndex ||
            !glGetUniformIndices ||
            !glUniformBlockBinding)
    {
        qDebug("Could not init function pointers");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

As highlighted in the answer which I accepted, Uniform Buffer Objects have an associated layout ( http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object ) and the Uniform Blocks have to be linked "twice" (read more here: http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut07%20Shared%20Uniforms.html ).

Hope this helps!